# How to add a stopping condition for Jacobian Matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def jacobi(m,numiter=100):

    #Number of rows determins the number of variables
    numvars = m.shape[0]

    #construct array for final iterations
    history = np.zeros((numvars,numiter))
    i = 1
    while(i < numiter): #Loop for numiter

        for v in range(numvars): # Loop over all variables
            current = m[v,numvars] # Start with left hand side (augmented side of matrix)
            for col in range(numvars): #Loop over columns
                if v != col: # Don't count colume for current variable
                    current = current - (m[v,col]*history[col, i-1]) #subtract other guesses form previous timestep
            current = current/m[v,v] #divide by current variable coefficent

            history[v,i] = current #Add this answer to the rest
        i = i + 1 #iterate


    #plot each variable
    for v in range(numvars):
        plt.plot(history[v,: i]);
    return history[:,i-1]
```

I have this code that calculates Jacobian method. How do I add a stopping condition for when the solutions converge? i.e. the values for the current iteration have changed less than some threshold `e` from the values for the previous iteration.

The threshold `e` will be an input to the function and the default value to 0.00001

Answer (score 0):

You could add another condition to your while loop, so when it reaches your error threshold it stops.

> ```
> def jacobi(m,numiter=100, error_threshold = 1e-4):
>
>   #Number of rows determins the number of variables
>   numvars = m.shape[0]
>
>   #construct array for final iterations
>   history = np.zeros((numvars,numiter))
>   i = 1
>   err = 10*error_threshold
>   while(i < numiter and err > error_threshold): #Loop for numiter and error threshold
>
>       for v in range(numvars): # Loop over all variables
>           current = m[v,numvars] # Start with left hand side (augmented side of matrix)
>           for col in range(numvars): #Loop over columns
>               if v != col: # Don't count colume for current variable
>                   current = current - (m[v,col]*history[col, i-1]) #subtract other guesses form previous timestep
>           current = current/m[v,v] #divide by current variable coefficent
>
>           history[v,i] = current #Add this answer to the rest
>       #check error here. In this case the maximum error
>       if i > 1:
>         err = max((history[:,i] - history[:,i-1])/history[:,i-1])
>
>       i = i + 1 #iterate
>
>
>
>   #plot each variable
>   for v in range(numvars):
>     plt.plot(history[v,: i]);
> return history[:,i-1]
> ```